# Apply webpack loaders to a code fragment

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Is there any way to make webpack to apply it's loaders to just a portion of a file? Here's a example of what I mean...

Let's say I have a bunch of loaders configured for `.scss` files. Would be awesome to be able write a component in any of the two following ways to produce the same output:

---

**1) Standard loaders**

component.js

```
import './component.scss';

export class Component {
...
```

component.scss

```
.component {
  background: #663399
}

...
```

---

**2) Custom loaders**

component.js

```
my-magic-import `
  .component {
    background: #663399
  }
`

export class Component {
...
```

---

How could I achieve something similar to the second case?
Could I somehow modify the way webpack identify the `requires`, `imports` and file extensions so it could be able to understand my custom syntax?
As last resort could one write a loader for js files that do this job for me?

Thanks for any hints about what should I read about to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using these 2 libraries with webpack to convert to a cssobj first, then to plain CSS after that.

https://github.com/cssobj/cssobj-converter (supports sass/less)

```
var converter = require('cssobj-converter')
var obj = converter('p { color: red; }') //obj is a css object
```

https://github.com/cssobj/cssobj

```
var cssobj = require('cssobj')
var result = cssobj(obj) // the result is a CSS string
```

You can write a globally unique function `__insertCSS` (in your app's index.js) which inserts *plain* CSS strings in the `head` element.

Now these libraries **only run on node**, so you need one more step to make it work in the browser: a string replacement plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin

In webpack config you should configure the replace plugin to search for a pattern like `/__insertCSS\(.*?\)/`, get the string argument, process it like shown above and replace it with the result.

In your webpack config:

```
var StringReplacePlugin = require("string-replace-webpack-plugin");
var converter = require('cssobj-converter')
var cssobj = require('cssobj')

function parseSass(str){
var obj = converter(str) //obj is a css object
return cssobj(obj) // the result is a CSS string
}
```

...in `module`:

```
    loaders: [
             // configure replacements for file patterns 
             { 
                test: /\.js(x?)$/,
                loader: StringReplacePlugin.replace({
                    replacements: [
                        {
                            pattern: /__insertCSS\(`(.*?)`\)/ig,
                            replacement: function (match, p1, offset, string) {
                               //p1 is the string enclosed by backticks
                                var cssStr =  parseSass(p1); 
                              //need to escape quotes with JSON in resulting string   
                                return '__insertCSS("' + JSON.stringify(cssStr) + '")'
                            }
                        }
                    ]})
                }
          ]
```

Mind you, I have not tested that, but it seems feasible at a first look.

This string replacement loader must come before babel, just put it first in the `loaders` array

Doc here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#loader-order

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely have a look later on today!

Comment: The way you used the string-replace plugin was essential for me to understand another way of getting this done. Thank you for the insight and for trying to help, much appreciated.